# Displaying map from MBTiles file using Leaflet and Flask results in only in map controls being displayed in web page

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, variables, flask, sqlite3-python

I'm trying to display a map from an MBTiles file using Leaflet, Flask and Sqlite3. I have an MBTiles file of the New Zealand map, and I want to display a location with latitude and longitude values on a web page. I am able to serve the tiles using a Flask route, but when I load the page in my browser, only the controls for the map are displayed, and the map itself is not visible.

Here is what the web page looks like:

[Web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSTwG.png)

Here's my Flask app code (`app.py`):

```
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def display_map():
    longitude = 175.6138189
    latitude = -40.34256356
    return render_template('map.html', lat=latitude, lon=longitude)

@app.route('/tiles/<int:z>/<int:x>/<int:y>.png')
def serve_tile(z, x, y):
    mbtiles_path = 'path/to/new-zealand.mbtiles'

    with sqlite3.connect(mbtiles_path) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            'SELECT tile_data FROM tiles WHERE zoom_level=? AND tile_column=? AND tile_row=?',
            (z, x, (2 ** z) - 1 - y)
        )
        tile = cursor.fetchone()
        if tile:
            return tile[0], 200, {
                'Content-Type': 'image/png',
                'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=3600'
            }
    return 'Tile not found', 404

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And here's my `map.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Location on Map</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100vh;"></div>
    <script>
        var lat = parseFloat("{{ lat|tojson|safe }}");
        var lon = parseFloat("{{ lon|tojson|safe }}");
        console.log("Latitude: ", lat);
        console.log("Longitude: ", lon);

        var map = L.map('map').setView([lat, lon], 13);
        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; OpenStreetMap contributors'
        }).addTo(map);

        L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(map).bindPopup("<b>Location</b><br>Latitude: " + lat + "<br>Longitude: " + lon).openPopup();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load the page in my browser, I get the following error in the console:

```
map.html:15 Latitude:  NaN
map.html:16 Longitude:  NaN
Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN)
    at new D (LatLng.js:32:9)
    at j (LatLng.js:123:11)
    at i.setView (Map.js:181:30)
    at map.html:18:32.
```

I suspect that the javascipt code is not receiving the latitude and longitude values from the `app.py`. That is probably why it is saying the above error.

**How can I resolve this issue and display the map with the correct location using the MBTiles file?**

I served the tiles using a Flask route, but encountered issues with displaying the map on the web page. I made changes to the Flask app code and HTML file to try to resolve the issue, such as passing the latitude and longitude values to the template using Flask's render_template function and using the tojson filter to convert the values to JSON.